# issue with mdDatepicker timezone

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-material

I have a mdDatepicker input that returned an error saying "Error: the ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. Currently the model is a string"  After some digging, I found this post on github: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6253 and replaced this piece of code found in the ngMaterial directive:

```
if (value && !(value instanceof Date)) {
        throw Error('The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. ' +
            'Currently the model is a: ' + (typeof value));
      }
```

with this:

```
 if (value && !(value instanceof Date)) {
    var parseValue = self.dateLocale.parseDate(value);
    if (isNaN(parseValue)) {
        throw Error('The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. ' +
        'Currently the model is a: ' + (typeof value));
    } else {
        value = parseValue;
    }
  }
```

That fixed the ng-model string issue, but now I'm faced with another issue, which is timezone.  When I click on the mdDatepicker now and choose 11/30/2017 for example, after pressing save and refreshing the page, the mdDatepicker always shows the day before.  In this case, it will show 11/29/2017 as the day chosen.

Is there something I can add to the above snippet of code that would fix this issue?  Any suggestions are appreciated!